# Queryable "artificial" fields in RoR Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to define an "artificial" field on a RoR model, defined as a function in the RDBMS?

As an example, suppose I have a model with a field `user_name`. `user_name` is always in the form "firstname lastname" (two strings separated by a space). In mysql, I can get the first name by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_name, ' ', 1)`.

I would like to define a field `first_name`, and have ActiveRecord always use the appropriate DB function for reading (and more importantly, querying) the field, so I could do this:

```
johns = User.where(:first_name => "John")
```

...and ActiveRecord would generate the correct SQL:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_name, ' ', 1) AS first_name 
FROM users 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_name, ' ', 1) = "John";
```

Comment: Why not just add a migration and have proper first_name / last_name columns?

Comment: @JohnNaegle, this is a simplified example. Actual implementation is significantly more complex, but boils down to the same idea (a field defined as a DB function on another field).

Answer (score 0):

You can have an [ActiveRecord scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) that does exactly that

```
scope :first_name ->(x) { where("SUBSTRING_INDEX(?, ' ', 1) as first_name", x) }
```

which will give the desired functionality to your AR model

```
johns = User.first_name("John")
```

UPDATE

We can also have a custom attribute reader, either by a simple method

```
def first_name
  user_name.split(" ").first
end
```

or if we want something more complex and extendable, through a value object

```
def first_name
  FirstName.new(self)
end
```

where `FirstName` is something like the following

```
class FirstName

  def initialize(user)
    self.first_name = user_name.a_production_method
    ...
    # other attributes here
  end

  def get_first_name
    first_name
  end

  # extra functionality here
end
```

Comment: This addresses half of the problem: A mechanism for querying. It doesn't actually provide the attribute first_name, however.

Comment: I think this is erroneous anyway. I believe you mean: scope :first_name, ->(x){ where("SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', 1) = ?", x) }   and johns = User.first_name("John")

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I appreciate it! The custom attribute reader requires doing the same thing in Ruby in one place (the attribute accessor), and SQL in another (the scope). What I want to do is combine those into one "thing" which uses only the SQL function.

Comment: since you apply logic that is not within rails' defaults, you have to implement it somehow in both layers, ruby and database (as rails does). I don't think there is a "magic" way to get it to work with only one part.